# cannot change width attribute in iframe

Tags: iframe

I am working with iframes. I have found the only place in the codebase where the iframe name is found. Despite my changing the attributes there, nothing happens. I empty the browser cache, still nothing happens. I cannot even find the value that's stuck in the codebase
'460px !important' anywhere in the codebase, and yet it persists. Any advice greatly appreciated. Thank you! It's been days.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this in any size in percent or pixel instead. I hope so it would be clear:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://google" style="border: 0; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Maziar! This is interesting. So, you make google the source of the frame? And then set attributes. Hmm. What turned out to be the issue was that the database had cached information from a session of mine including the property 460px !important. No matter what I did, nothing fixed it because it was loading from the database. I couldn't find the property width for the element with those attributes anywhere in the codebase. I had actually hit the database cache almost 1200 times?!Problem solved. Do you mean by your example above that you would actually load the frame from google?

Comment: So, there was nothing that could have reversed what I had done, apart from clearing the cache. Especially since the attribute I had set was defined inline and given the setting !important, which, due to its placement inline either makes the instruction double-extra inviolable or makes no difference. eheh.